# switching between Activities in Android AND passing objects

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin

my android app has a lot of `Activities`.
As of now, I am calling `Finish()` each time I start a new `Activity`.

So my previous one is completely destroyed and when user presses the back button, I finish current activity and start a new `Intent` of the previous activity.

This is making my app very slow because it has to run `OnCreate` every time I start an activity.

If I don't finish the previous activity, how can I call the previous activity without finishing this one? User will be opening the same activities bunch of times.

I also want to use `.PutExtra()` when they are switching between activities.

this is what I am doing now:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, typeof(AddNewActivity));
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (myDataObject);
intent.PutExtra ("myDataObject", json);
StartActivity (intent);
Finish ();
```

So basically, my question is how can I not start a new `Activity` each time and still pass data between two or more activities?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to simply not call "finish()" every time you go to a new activity.  If you follow this approach, the back-button will take the user back to the existing instance of the previous activity.  Thus you get to bypass onCreate and any time-consuming operations within.

As for passing data: use Intents.  When launching a new activity, call startActivityForResult.  This will allow you to:

- Pass data to the new Activity in an Intent.
- Pass data back to the original Activity when the new Activity is done.

See: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: I understand that concept but when the user does press back, I want to send some data with it. is that possible? that was my main question.  for example, how can I send a json object with it?

Comment: See my update to the question.  startActivityForResult allows you to pass data between Activities (using Intents of course).

Comment: Ok this looks very promising.  I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: I have a question.  I am very new to this so please ignore my ignorance.  Let's say I have 4 activities.  User goes from one to another and they all are opened at some point. If I don't kill any of them and I am on the 4th one, how can i go back to the 2nd one without killing any of the 4 activities? If I make a new `Intent` and call `StartActivity` it would start a new one, correct?

Comment: An activity should only be considered done if (a) the user takes an action that completes the purpose of the activity - e.g. pressing a Done button on a form, or (b) if the user presses the Android Back button.  Other actions, such as selecting a list item to view the details of that item, should navigate to a new activity without finishing the launching activity.  Think of it like a web browser (that's what Android design is based on BTW).  Navigating forward, by clicking on a link is analogous to launching a new activity.  Clicking the back button finishes the page/activity.

Comment: You should probably give this a read: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html.

Comment: Bottom limns - if your app is launching a new activity, make an intelligent choice about whether or not the user needs to return to the previous activity.  If no - then finish the previous activity.  If yes - then do not.

Comment: Read the above link and familiarize yourself with the Android activity stack.  This is a very fundamental concept for the Android platform.

Comment: Thank you! I went through that link and it really helped. Thanks again.